# Convert a serialized array output in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In Wordpress, I have some post *meta_key* fields with strings of this form, from an serialized array, with a variable length:

```
a:2:{i:0;i:281;i:1;i:282;}
```

I need to copy them to other post *meta_key* fields, but in this format:

```
[281,282]
```

How can I do this?

My code:

```
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
   $attachmentIds = array();
   foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
      $attachmentIds[] = $attachment->ID;
   }
}

$data['meta_input']['advert_post_attachments'] = $attachmentIds;
```

**P.S. I apologize to those who were angry with my question! I am not a PHP programmer, I'm really not a programmer at all, but I need to solve this.**

I checked the recommended by @Machavity answers, they are very educational, but this doesn't helped me to solve my problem.

**[SOLVED]**

**I thank everyone who tried to help me: @AbraCadaver, @Anant,  @ManinderpreetSingh, @ShaktiPhartiyal and, sure, @Machavity!** :)

Comment: unserialize($array)

Comment: lurie `[281,282]` is array  or you are going to treat it as a string  like `'[281,282]'`?

Comment: `$result = json_encode(unserialize('a:2:{i:0;i:281;i:1;i:282;}'));`

Comment: @Anant I see this in phpMyAdmin, so I think this is a string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tested your solution by replacing the quoted string with the array name that puts this string in the post `meta_key`, but I got as a result only a `false` output.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the unserialize() function and then join the output to create an array like format:
You can use:

```
<?php
$sData = 'a:2:{i:0;i:281;i:1;i:282;}';
$uData = unserialize($sData);
$arrFormat = "[".implode(",",$uData)."]";
echo $arrFormat;
```

this will give you the output:

```
[281,282]
```

Comment: Your code works well on http://phptester.net/, but not on my site. I tested it by replacing the string `'a:2:{i:0;i:281;i:1;i:282;}'` with the array name that puts this string in a `meta_key` field (`$sData = $attachmentIds;`), and as a result I have only the brackets without content.

Comment: Can you tell me your server php version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: try doing a var_dump of $attachmentIds; and please share the output

Comment: lurin did you checked my answer second part

Comment: @Anant Yes, but the output of `var_dump($data);` (and also of `var_dump($attachmentIds);`) is `NULL`.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal The output is `NULL`.

Comment: lurin from where this:-`$attachmentIds` came into picture?

Comment: @Anant I suppose that's probably where the serialised data is coming from.

Comment: @Anant I updated the question with my code. The code works, as I have that string with IDs.

Comment: @Iurie  what is the output of `var_dump ($data['meta_input']['advert_post_attachments']);`?

Comment: @Anant I don't see anywhere the output of `var_dump($data['meta_input']['advert_post_attachments']);`, so I copied it to a new `meta_key` field with `$data['meta_input']['advert_var_dump'] = var_dump($data['meta_input']['advert_post_attachments']);`. The result is `NULL`. But the string with IDs in discussion is constantly present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that I found in a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpadverts/):

```
...

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
   $attachmentIds = array();
   foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
      $attachmentIds[] = $attachment->ID;
   }

$dirty_ordered_keys = $attachmentIds;
$length = sizeof($dirty_ordered_keys);
$clean_ordered_keys = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
    $clean_ordered_keys[$i] = intval($dirty_ordered_keys[$i]);
}

$clean_ordered_keys_json = json_encode($clean_ordered_keys);
$data['meta_input']['advert_post_attachments'] = $clean_ordered_keys_json;
```